# Evince Document Viewer(42.0) does not remember last page in 22.04

Tags: pdf, evince, 22.04

Just switched from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and realized that Document Viewer no longer open on the last viewed page and doesn't remember the side pane preference even after using the "Save Current Settings as Default" option.

when entered evince in the terminal this error message appears:

**added**

(evince:4680): dbind-WARNING **: 16:52:55.494: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_1: Permission denied

Tried:

sudo chown username:username ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
sudo chmod 600 ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home

which did not resolve the problem.

The bookmark option does not work either

**Update** 
Somebody added in launchpad that it could be related to apparmor, and I've tried temporarily disabling it with `sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` as suggested by the poster. And both issues were solved.

Now the question is whether it is safe to permanently disable evince profile from apparmor or wait for a software update from evince.

Kindly advise

Comment: File a bug report.

Comment: can't seems to be able to file a bug report via alt f2. typed in the ubuntu-bug <Document Viewer> and nothing happened. tried ubuntu-bug and select other and get no package specified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: thanks, bug reported. Will revert back when resolved

Comment: Bug reported via https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896

Comment: I am facing the same problem in ubuntu 22.04. the ocument viewer is not remember the page it left off last.

Comment: I'm starting to repent of installing 22.04 I think.

Comment: You can create a symlink if you want your change to persist after reboot.
`ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.bin.evince`

Answer (score 0):

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896) has been resolved in release `42.3`. Consider upgrading Evince Document Viewer.