# Accessibility Bus error: Permission Denied warning when opening PDF documents

Tags: evince, 22.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10 and then to Ubuntu 22.04.

After the upgrade whenever I try to open any pdf document via the terminal using `xdg-open` I get the following warning:

`(evince:13596): dbind-WARNING **: 15:18:14.588: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/at-spi/bus_0: Permission denied`.

I did not have this problem in Ubuntu 20.04 (I did not check this with Ubuntu 21.10). I find that because of this I do not get the nice list of sections/chapters in the left pane in doc viewer and it also does not keep track of the page number at which I left off a document.

Doing `export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1` silences the warning but does not solve the problem.

I would like to be able to use the accessibility features which get disabled due to this error.

Any suggestions for fixing this problem are welcome.

**NOTE**: I am using Xorg with Ubuntu 22.04. I tried Wayland as well but the problem persists.

Comment: This might be a bug associated with AppArmour, since it's a permission error:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403672/evince-document-viewer42-0-does-not-remember-last-page-in-22-04

Comment: this is likely the answer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896/comments/21 Please try this  and if it works answer this question :)

Comment: As mentioned by R.Alberto and Rinzwind, the problem is related to AppArmor. I tried to run evince with AppArmor disabled as mentioned here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1969896/comments/21 and it worked. For now I have disabled AppArmor for the evince profile.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently a known bug in the community.
Check [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230238/x-applications-warn-couldnt-connect-to-accessibility-bus-on-stderr/230442#230442).

Basically, if you don't need Accessibility features, you can just type in the following command in the Terminal:

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```