# Ubuntu Document Viewer cann't add bookmark

Tags: bookmarks

I have a problem with Ubuntu Document Viewer. There is no possibility to add bookmarks to documents because button "Add bookmark" is disabled (see attached screen):

[image: Screen of document]

It's strange because the problem arises after reinstallation of VM Ubuntu. There was no such problem at my first VM Ubuntu. I searched solution of this problem but couldn't find it. I will be pleased for any idea how to add bookmarks.

Comment: Have you switched to Ubuntu 22.04 recently? `evince` has many bugs in Ubuntu 22.04. I guess this is another one.

Comment: not that is a viable answer, but evince bookmarks (on my 20.04) system are kept in a metadata file called ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home ... maybe your system is having a problem accessing that file... Sounds like it could be much more involved though

Comment: @FedKad Yes, some days ago. Maybe it's really a bug. In this case I hope it will be corrected in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue myself. Furthermore, previous bookmarks I made were not saved. Found the solution in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403672/evince-document-viewer42-0-does-not-remember-last-page-in-22-04)

This command solved the problem:

`sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`